# How does this program work C?

Tags: c, image, fade, bmp

```
void fade(ImagenBMP *imagen1, ImagenBMP *imagen2, int f) {
float v = (float)f/255;
for (int i = 0; i < imagen1->tamanyo; i++) {
    imagen1->datos[i] = (imagen1->datos[i] - imagen2->datos[i])*v + imagen2->datos[i];
}}; //end of fade
```

It's supose to fade two images into a single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite the equation, you will end up with:

```
imagen1->datos[i] = v*imagen1->datos[i] + (1-v)*imagen2->datos[i];
```

This is how the blend works. You are specifying how much of the first image (out of 255 parts) should be included in the function parameter `f`, `255-f` parts will be included from the second image.

Comment: You're right, I had the following equation: Pixel_result = Pixel_imgA * fade + Pixel_imgB * (1 – fade); but I couldn't see the relation with the code at that moment. Now I see it crearly, thanks mate.